# Updating remote repo if a file gets deleted from the local repository

Tags: git, github

I have executed the following with only one master branch:

1) Pushed my local repo to remote repo in github.

2)  Deleted 1 file from my local repo {not by git rm but just rigth click and delete}.

Now When I try to do commit the changes to github it doesn't and gives me the following error:

```
  0 [main] vim 90884 C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vim.exe: *** fatal error - cmalloc would have returned NULL 3466 [main] vim 90884 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to vim.exe.stackdump Aborting commit due to empty commit message.
```

Note: My remote repo has still the file whihc I deleted from my local repo.

Q1. I know this is not the proper way. I want to know the reason why the changes are not taken taken into account?

Q2. After this, if I tried to update my local repo with git pull origin master. But it didnt pull the file from the remote repo. Why?

Comment: Have you _committed_ the deletion?

Comment: Yes I tried to commit and got the error I mentioned above. I want to know why deleting any file from the local repo without the git rm -r, i snot detected?

Comment: Have you _added_ the deletion prior to committing? Can you share what `git status` reports?